# удалить лишние теги и значения из строк в БД MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

есть множество строк в БД содержащих html разметку изображения, вида:

```
<img src="https://exaple.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image.jpg" alt="vBulletin logo, logotype" width="250" height="250" />
```

как удалить все и оставить только прямую ссылку `https://exaple.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image.jpg`

применительно ко всем записям.

Answer (score 0):

вначале обрезал до <img src="
командой REPLACE
после удалил все после "
командой UPDATE images SET img = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`img`, '%"%', 1);